# OS X 10.9 update has stopped .apk jarsigner working

Tags: java, android, macos, osx-mavericks

I have been packaging sencha/phonegap applications for Android and everything was working before updating to OS X Mavericks 10.9 but now I follow the same procedure and the apk gets signed and zipaligned but installation on a phone causes an error. The first packaging try threw an error to download JDK so I did and then the next tries worked until installation without error.

From ADB I was getting the error

```
[INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

Which lead me to believe the update removed some java paths.

I've reinstalled JDK and changed my $ vi ~/.bash_profile to include the following line:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home
```

following instructions from: [here](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/02/26/how-to-set-the-java_home-variable-in-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/)

Now I don't get errors until installation and it just says "Application not installed"

The process I use is; unpackage existing .apk, modify manifest, replace contents, rebuild .apk, jarsign using certificate, zipalign for installation.

I think there might be more environment variables and paths that I need to configure but not sure where to start. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Android strictly needs Java 1.6 to do jarsigner. Please make sure that your Java is 1.6, not 1.7

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue, I don't know why it prompted a new install of the JDK, I had to delete 1.7 and restart for OS X default 1.6. Everything working now, can't thank you enough @Krypton

Comment: I'm glad that it helps. I moved it to answer part so that later on some one with same problem can find a solution. Accept and upvote if you like :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android strictly needs Java 1.6 to do jarsigner. Please make sure that Java 1.6, not 1.7, is installed